# setTimeout() keeps restarting react

Tags: reactjs

I have a popup that should open after 30 secs. Therefore my function looks something like what's shown below. But it keeps repeating popping up again after I have closed it - after 30 seconds or less. What am I doing wrong?

```
export default function MyElement() {

 const [popupper, setPopupper] = React.useState(false);

 const handlePopupClick = () => {
    setPopupper(!popupper);
 }

 useEffect(() => setTimeout(() => {
   setTimeout(() => {
      setPopupper(true);
   }, 30000);
 });

 return (
   <div name='popupthing' hidden={!popupper}>
     ....
   </div>
 ); 
}
```

Comment: You should check if the component [is still mounted](https://github.com/jmlweb/isMounted) before you call setPopupper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set empty array as the second param for useEffect, essentially telling react to only run the passed function after the initial render:

```
useEffect(() => setTimeout(() => {
   setTimeout(() => {
     setPopupper(true);
   }, 30000);
}, []); // Add empty array here.
```

The [docs give an in-depth explanation if you're interested.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you add a empty array at the end of the `useEffect` (just like a callback), it will wokf only in the first render of the component ( It will me similar to use `componentDidMount`). IF you add a variable inside the Array it will update only if the variable changes its value.

So thats why its restarting every time you rerender your component.

```
useEffect(() => setTimeout(() => {
   setTimeout(() => {
     setPopupper(true);
   }, 30000);
},
[]);
```